# Software Configuration Management in the cloud?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, hudson, github, amazon-ec2

I'm a CS student, just exploring the SCM space. While doing my own research I came across many different hosted solutions (GitHub obviously, Lighthouse, YouTrack, TeamCity, etc.) - do you think it is actually reasonable to try to host a (commercial, closed source) project entirely in the cloud?

Let's say I'd host code on GitHub, use Jira or Lighthouse for issue tracking, God knows what other hosted PM solution (Basecamp?) and build using EC2 (I can put Hudson or TeamCity on it and use appropriate EC2 plugins for these products to get more computing power when needed).

Is the EC2 bill going to kill me (compared to self-hosted solutions)? Do you think "the cloud" it's still not reliable enough?

Comment: Try [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com). It includes Subversion, Trac, and Hudson. All in one package, free for commercial (!) projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way we work at our company. Version control system (git) + agile planning + ticket system/bugtracker + wiki are hosted at http://www.assembla.com for 49$/month for 40 users, private repositories ( https://www.assembla.com/plans ) and we have a micro instance on amazon aws ec2 where jenkins, nexus, sonar and some internals tools are running for free the first year and then you should consider spending like 80$/month for the same service.

So it costs 129$/month for a full cloud solution for a small company (40 users max): reliable, with a good release train of new features by our service providers and with a low maintenance footprint for us.

Compared to self hosted it's not really expensive considering the following costs :
- price of your server (lets say 1000$)
- electricity bills (lets say 30$/month for 100% uptime)
- cost of configuration (to get the same quality as assembla for exemple) and maintenance (lets say 0.5day man per month at 500$/day in france)
The cost is : 363$/month

This should look a bit biased, but finally it's what we experienced.

Regards,

Xavier

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem to use the cloud for hosting, and many large companies do so already. I think NetFlix recently moved solely to EC2. Our whole business runs on EC2, and it's been relatively good so far.

The EC2 bill is up to you to manage -- cloud is all about granular billing for services, and the more you consume the more you pay (we sell a tool that helps with cost controls: http://LabSlice.com). Your biggest cost will usually be CPU power, so stick to the Micro/Small instances until you've got a handle on costs.

It's interesting that people question the reliability of cloud, as the underlying premise is actually to provide more reliability to businesses then they could afford themselves (high scalability, immediate availability of hardware, monitoring, load balancing etc.)

Comment: If you're concerned about costs then also check http://blog.labslice.com/2011/01/3-ways-to-reduce-your-amazon-ec2-cloud.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of AWS Free Account and host your application. If you exceed Free Account Usage limit,you will be charged for whatever extra you have utilized.

Regarding reliability about Cloud, every big firm is moving towards Cloud like Amazon,Microsoft,IBM,HP etc because they found cloud reliable,cost effective and green.

Answer (score 0):

Given your a student and assuming your looking to spend little money, a lot of Git and SVN hosting providers offer free hosting for students or free accounts if your a small team with minimal storage requirements. Check out [Codesion's](http://codesion.com/products/student-plan.html) student offering for example (disclaimer, I work for Codesion). This plan also comes with Trac / Bugzilla for your PM requirements. I wouldn't be concerned with security and reliability for the same reason that Simon points out above.

As for CI on EC2 - this is probably your best bet since you pay by the hour each instance is running. I'd recommend using Amazons API to fire up an instance each time Hudson needs to perform a build, store the results of the build on more permanent storage, and shut the instance down when finished. If your doing a lot of CI builds, it might be better to just keep the instance running, but this will cost you more of course.